# Mudar de cor CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Boa tarde, estou com uma duvida como que eu posso fazer para mudar a cor de uma div passando o mouse em outra por exemplo:

tenho duas div com o nome da primeira div de 1 e a segunda div com o nome de 2 ambos são dar cor preta, quando eu passar o mouse na div 2 ele muda a cor para vermelho na div 2 e na div 1 automaticamente, teria como alguem poder me ajudar ?

Comment: Quer passar o mouse por cima da primeira e mudar a cor da segunda e vice versa ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com CSS, desde que o elemento a mudar seja filho do elemento a fazer hover:

```css
div:hover h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Olá</h1>
  <h2>Adeus</h2>
</div>
```

Com mais liberdade, qualquer elemento hover ativa qualquer outro do DOM:

```js
$('h1').hover(
    function () {
        $('h2').css({'color': 'red'});          
     },
     function () {
        $('h2').css({'color': 'black'});   
     }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Olá</h1>
<h2>Adeus</h2>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: De nada @Nathan

Answer (score 2):

Se fosse pra mudar apenas na div 2 você poderia utilizar o evento `:hover` do CSS.

```js
$("#dois").on("mouseover", function() {
  $("#um").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#dois").css("background-color", "red");
});

$("#dois").on("mouseout", function() {
  $("#um").css("background-color", "black");
  $("#dois").css("background-color", "black");
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="um" class="box">1</div>
<div id="dois" class="box">2</div>
```